# MAKEFILE using Library : Linker command failed

Tags: c, makefile

Hello I can't make my Makefile working with
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INC) $(OBJS) $(MLX_LNK) -o $(NAME).
got a

```
clang -O3 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -I  -I cub3d.h src/cub3d.o src/checks/argvcheck.o src/checks/parse_map.o src/libft/basics.o src/libft/basics_bis.o src/libft/get_next_line.o src/utils/errors.o -L minilibx_opengl -lmlx -framework OpenGL -framework AppKit -o cub3D
clang: error: cannot specify -o when generating multiple output files
make: *** [cub3D] Error 1
```

The command on terminal I do is "make test1"

I also tried with $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -I $(HEADER) $(OBJS) $(MLX_LNK) -o $(NAME).

but got

```
Compiling...
clang -O3 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -I cub3d.h src/cub3d.o src/checks/argvcheck.o src/checks/parse_map.o src/libft/basics.o src/libft/basics_bis.o src/libft/get_next_line.o src/utils/errors.o -L minilibx_opengl -lmlx -framework OpenGL -framework AppKit -o cub3D
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_init_cube", referenced from:
      _init_game in cub3d.o
  "_write_errors", referenced from:
      _verify_line in argvcheck.o
      _ft_parse_cub in argvcheck.o
      _my_get_next_line in get_next_line.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Many thanks for your help

Makefile here :

`````
NAME = cub3D

HEADER = cub3d.h

CC = clang
CFLAGS = -O3 -Wall -Wextra -Werror

INC = -I $(MLX-DIR) -I $(HEADER)

MLX_DIR = minilibx_opengl
MLX_LNK = -L $(MLX_DIR) -lmlx -framework OpenGL -framework AppKit

SRCS = src/main.c \
        src/checks/argvcheck.c \
        src/libft/basics.c \
        src/libft/get_next_line.c \
        src/utils/errors.c \

OBJS = $(SRCS.c=.o)

all: $(NAME)

mlx: $(MLX-DIR)
    @echo "\033[34m-= Making libX.a... =-"
    @make -C $(MLX_DIR)   

$(NAME): ${OBJS} mlx
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INC) $(OBJS) $(MLX_LNK) -o $(NAME)
   

test1: $(NAME) 
    $(NAME) ; ./a.out maps/test1.cub

clean:
    @echo "\033[0;31mCleaning..."
    rm -f $(OBJS)
    # + $(B_OBJ)
    # + rm -f bitmap.bmp
    @echo "\033[0m"

fclean: clean
    @echo "\033[34m-= Cleaning mlx... =-"
    @make clean -C $(MLX_DIR)
    @echo "\033[0;31mRemoving executable..."
    rm -f $(NAME)
    @echo "\033[0m"

re: fclean all

.PHONY: all clean fclean re

````
`````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first of all this is wrong:

```
OBJS = $(SRCS.c=.o)
```

You're missing a `:` here, it should be `$(SRCS:.c=.o)`  As a result, `OBJS` will be empty.

Next, this is not causing you problems at the moment but is not right: you should always use `$(MAKE)` never a raw command like `make` when invoking a sub-make.

Finally, the way you've written your question by embedding results into the middle of the makefile makes it very hard to read.  Please put the makefile first, then separate sections for different attempts at recipes.  And you need to include the command line that make printed out (cut and paste the exact line please!) for us to see what the command being run it (with all variables expanded).  Typically it becomes VERY obvious what the problem is if you look at that.

For example in this case you'd see that there are actually no object files in the link line, so it should be clear that the `$(OBJS)` variable is not being set properly.

**EDIT**

OK, thanks for showing the command line.  Now, you should look at it carefully and you will see your problem :).  Look at this here:

```
clang -O3 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -I  -I cub3d.h src/cub3d.o ...
```

Does that look right to you?  Look specifically at `-I -I cub3d.h`... does that seem right?

What happens is that the compiler expects a pathname to come after the `-I` and there isn't one, so it treats the second `-I` as the pathname.  Then the file `cub3d.h` is treated as a source file, and you can't link a source file with object files.

So why does this look like this?  Look at your makefile:

```
INC = -I $(MLX-DIR) -I $(HEADER)
```

so the missing thing is where `$(MLX-DIR)` goes.  What is that variable?  Well you have this:

```
MLX_DIR = minilibx_opengl
```

but this is not the same thing because it uses an *underscore* whereas the reference uses a *dash*.  So, make them the same.

Then you'll see that it's not valid to put a file as an argument to `-I`.  That takes a *directory* to search for header files.  If you want to include the header you have to add `#include "cub3d.h"` in your source code, not add it to the compile line.

Comment: Thanks for the missing ":", now I know why the executive was disappearing. 
Sorry for the confusion, here is a cleaner Makefile.

Comment: I should also say, it's useless to add `-I` options to the link line.  The linker doesn't search for headers, the compiler searches for headers.  `-I` options should be added to the compile line.  You can add that to `CFLAGS` if you want, or you can set the `CPPFLAGS` variable instead of using `INC` (`CPPFLAGS` is the default variable holding preprocessor options like `-I` or `-D`).

Comment: Thank you very much for this lesson, it works finally well now !